# Buscar controles em uma classe separada da Activity principal

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

Preciso buscar os controles para alterção de valores no layout. Porém passando o contexto por parâmetro para a classe ele não encontra os controles declarados no xml retornando null para cada cast feito.

A classe onde estou tentando recuperar estes dados extende AsyncTask:

```
public class WSCatalogo91 extends AsyncTask<Void, ProgressAux, Boolean> 

private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
private TextView mProgressText;

public WSCatalogo91(WSCatalogo91Listener listener) throws SQLException {
        this.listener = listener;
        dh = new DatabaseHelper((Activity) listener);
        confDao = new ConfiguracaoDao(dh.getConnectionSource());
        pDao = new ProdutoDao(dh.getConnectionSource());

        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) ((Activity) listener).findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        mProgressText = (TextView) ((Activity) listener).findViewById(R.id.progressBarTextView);
        auxProgresso = new ProgressAux();
    }
```

mProgressBar e mProgressText estão nulos, porém meu contexto ai não é nulo, tanto que ele esta sendo usado nas linhas de cima perfeitamente. Segue o código xml onde declaro os ids.

```
<TextView android:text="@string/progressBar" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:id="@+id/progressBarTextView"
        android:maxWidth="400dp"
        android:maxHeight="400dp"/>

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="165dp"
        android:minWidth="300dp" />
```

Comment: já tentou utilizar `mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) MainActivity.findViewById(R.id.progressBar)`?

Comment: @PauloRoberto essa classe não esta declarada dentro da Activity, creio que não seria uma boa prática.

Comment: porque esta classe não está declarada dentro da Activity? porquê você crê que não seria uma boa prática? é que no android geralmente eu utilizo imports ou buscando da MainActivity como eu te disse para achar elementos xml

Comment: Para que você possa encontrar estes elementos, você deve chamar a Activity que está com o `this.setContentView(R.layout.nomedoseuLayout)` setado no `onCreate()` e utilizala como namespace no lugar de `MainActivity` no exemplo q te mostrei

Comment: @PauloRoberto Ponha como resposta, se for isso eu já coloco como resposta certa e você ganha seus pontos. Aguardo a resposta.

Comment: O correto é você testar se funcionou primeiro pois não tive tempo para testar, pode ser?

Comment: @PauloRoberto Eu não entendi muito bem o que você quer dizer, no onCreate() que é dentro da Activity o setContentView esta funcionando normalmente. Porém quando passo o contexto para a minha outra classe, terei que fazer de novo la dentro o mesmo processo?

Comment: Depende, se **"sua outra classe"** for uma Activity, você pode fazer isto sim, irá funcionar. Porém se ela não for, aí você tem que dar um import na sua Activity e utilizar o nome dela como namespace `SuaActivityQueTemOSetContentViewFuncionando.findViewById(R.id.progressBar)`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19084/discussion-between-luiz-negrini-and-paulo-roberto).